# How to use part of the request in the next iteration of the loop controller of Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]How can I take a part of request and use it in the next request of Jmeter? (I'm trying to record an application where after logging in we have 100 rows displayed and when we scroll after reaching the 100 limit a lazyloading call goes to the server and 50 more records are fetched. The call here is in JSON format and for the first scroll it sends across all the 100 records as request and in response we get 50 new records. Now when we scroll beyond 150 records, the request takes all 150 records as request but the response again is 50 and for the next scroll the request count would be 200, cumulatinve. Now I am trying to put a loop controller there and do the rest of scrolling in the loop). Every lazyloading call will give only 50 records but for the next iteration of request cumulative number of records are sent as requests.

My intuition says to use a pre-processor and post processor together for this. SInce, I am new to Jmeter, I am not sure which pre-processor for this purpose or if there is any other alternative to solve this.

If default page response is, "fgAhi" and I need value "A" to pass in the first Json request. So the first request would be something like "xAy" and the response is "pBq". Now for the second iteration I need the request to be "xABy" and response will be "pCq". Third request will be "xABCy" and response be "pDq" and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to join 2 JSON entities (i.e. 50 records from first response and 50 from second response into a new JSON object of 100 records you can use JSR223 [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) for this. Example code will be something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def previousResponse = vars.get('previousResponse')

def currentResponse = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

log.info('Previous response: ' + previousResponse)
log.info('Current response: ' +  currentResponse)

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json1 = slurper.parseText(previousResponse)
def json2 = slurper.parseText(currentResponse)

def cumulativeResponse = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson ([json1, json2]))

log.info('Cumulative response: ' + cumulativeResponse)

vars.put('previousResponse', cumulativeResponse)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy JSON Merge]

References:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: But this is not what I want. There is a json method that always has the output of 50 records. but the request is always the cumulative. Like when I logged in by default there are 100 records and after executing the json for the first time 50 new records have come. the next JSON REQUEST needs to have 150 (by default 100 + 50 in the first response), and the second response would be 50 records and the third JSON REQUEST will not have 200 records (100 default + 50 first response records + 50 second response records). I need to put this in loop for infinite times.

Comment: and the second response would be 50 records and the third JSON REQUEST will have 200 records (100 default + 50 first response records + 50 second response records)